# Limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x+1}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x-1} + \dfrac{1}{x+1}}{x}$$

I know that you are somehow supposed to join the numerators but that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: $$\frac{\dfrac1{1-x}+\dfrac1{1-x}}x=\frac{\dfrac2{1-x}}x=\frac2{x(1-x)}$$

Comment: The second 1-x should be 1+x . Sorry

Comment: Then $$\frac{\dfrac1{1-x}+\dfrac1{1+x}}x=\frac{\dfrac2{1-x^2}}x=\frac2{x(1-x^2)}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: How about you make that an answer to stop the flood of unanswered questions?

Comment: @thomas The edit doesn't seem correct

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{1+x}}{x} = \frac{1}{x} \frac{1+x+x-1}{x^2-1} = \frac{2x}{x(x^2-1)} = \frac{2}{x^2-1} \to_{x\to0}-2.
$$
Or you can do this with power series if you like:
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{1+x}}{x}=\frac{-\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-(-x)}}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n \right) = \frac{1}{x}\left(-1-x-x^2-\ldots+1-x+x^2-\ldots\right) = -2 + O(x).
$$
And as $x\to0$ you get $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, and in order to stop having so many non-answered questions:

$$\frac{\frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x+1}}{x}=\frac2{(-1+x^2)}$$

But then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac2{-1+x^2}=-2.$$